# Coderbits - Intelligent portfolios for developers and designers

Tags: app

https://coderbits.com

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

### About

Resumes are inadequate at verifying skills, traits, and knowledge that software developers and designers possess.

Coderbits is a network for software developers and designers that automatically builds knowledge portfolios using 50+ data sources. Portfolios are built using source code, packages, designs, education, organizations, and much more. Our unique award system of 500+ badges and core trait scores is designed to be fun and encourage personal growth.

Your work should speak for itself.

### StackOverflow Integration

Coderbits integrates StackOverflow as one of the many sites for profile aggregation. Let your work on StackOverflow build a detailed profile showing your skills and talents.

### License

Coderbits is a free service that is currently in an invite only beta. Invites can be requested on the site.

### Contact

Contact us via [Twitter](https://twitter.com/coderbits) or email us at social[at]coderbits[dot]com.

### Join us

https://coderbits.com